# How can I update few useState just for one render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a little question about re-render with useState.
For example, I have five useState methods:

```
setFirstState(someValue);
setSecondState(someValueSecond);
setThirdState(someValueThird);
...
```

And I want for this all just one render with react hooks. Can you explane me or maybe some example?

Comment: Why do you want this? I think there should be a better way instead of doing this. Can you put your code for the context.

Comment: Please put your real code, instead of a generic representation of it. It will help us give you a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine it with `useEffect` with **empty deps**.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const MyComp = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState('initialVal');
  useEffect(() => {
    setVal('newVal');
  }, []);
// --^    - this is an empty dependency list 
  return <div>Hello</div>;
};
```

Comment: He said `I have a little question about re-render with useState` so I do not think he is talking about running a code "on Mount", but to avoid to trigger too many re-renders

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all those into one state.

```
setCombinedState({
  first: someValue,
  second: someValueSecond,
  third: someValueThird,
});
```

:) Hope that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would like to use `useReducer` instead, and initiate it with an object with your (first, second, third...) properties, and then modify the one you want each time.

Declare your initial values

```
const initialState = {
  someValue: 'someValue',
  someValueSecond: 'someValueSecond',
  someValueThird: 'someValueThird',
}
```

set it

```
const [val, setVal] = React.useReducer(initalState);
```

And modify then whenever you need it.

```
setVal({someValue: 'anotherValue'});
setVal({someValueSecond: 'anotherValue'});
setVal({someValueThird: 'anotherValue'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you want to change multiple states at the same time, it usually means that these states are couples in some manner.

**Example**

Take for instance this case: You want to fetch some data from an API, so you would have the following states:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
const [error, setError] = useState(false)
const [data, setData] = useState(undefined)
```

Usually when one of these states changes, the others do as well.

This is a clear case where you should use `useReducer`.

For instance, like this:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'error':
      return {error: action.payload.error, loading: false };
    case 'fetched':
      return {data: action.payload.data, loading: false };
    case 'loading':
      return {loading: true};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
```

And after this, you could make a custom hook to manage these states:

```
const {loading, error, data, dispatch} = useFetchingData()
```

---

**To sum up**

This is just an example, but I would recommend you to take a look at your case, and see if these states you are talking about are somehow connected, and could be better arranged in this manner.

Reducers need more code that the one I posted here. I just wrote the reducer function. If you want to know more about how they work, I recommend you to [read the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).

If you want to update your question with the actual case you are facing right now, I could help you further.